# Save partially filled form (in symfony environment)

Tags: php, forms, symfony

This a kind of a generic question : 
i'm developping an application with Symfony and i have several big forms : many fields, with dynamic creation of other group of fields (collections).

1) I can't split those forms because

- it would break the established ergonomy
- the underlying tables are deeply interconnected

2) The user have credentials, so there is a session timeout
3) The user doesn't have necessarily all the information to fill all the fields at one time

But **the client wants to be able to fill this form *partially*, and have a "save for now" feature even if some mandatory fields are not filled**.

I can forget the cookies to do the trick because there are so many fields, including long text.
Since some of the mandatory fields can be empty, i can forget the save/edit later.

I haven't found a good solution for this problem.

- I was told to have a second database with all the constraint gone where the partially filled data would be saved but i don't like the idea of managing two databases in parallel and how to sync them.
- I could imagine to save all the data in a json/text format for later reinjection, but this is costly in terms of performance i think.

What strategy could be followed ? Has anyone had this kind of problem ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use a [DTO](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html) for the form where all mandatory fields can accept also null: if a user press to "save for now" you'll not perform any action. IF they press "save", you'll perform validation against DTO and if all is good, pours all data into "real" object and then save it.

I can't provide code, hope it's clear.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I have never used such a thing (i've just seen the name sometimes) and no clue how to implement it. But i will do some search. Thanks

Comment: So on "save for now" you save the DTO to database that's it?

Comment: @Veve: yes, DTO can have "an invalid" state in this case